# Verify work email with an OTP

Tags: email-verification

I have been working on a website, where work email is an important part of the website. But due to some restrictions, we can not make official email verification mandatory.

Currently, OTP will be sent to the provided work email and which has be entered to verify.

It is a non mandatory field.
Currently, we added a button "Send OTP to verify" just after work email field followed by a field "Enter OTP", but the conversion rate is less than ~4% of users that verify the email.

We also used popup for Entering OTP, but those are not good Idea as per conversion is concern .

Any help??

Comment: Can you explain the use case better please? What does that button do? How does it help in verification? What is your goal?

Comment: It is the business requirements, having official or work email verified will benefit business operations

Comment: Still more context is needed. Can you tell what the website/form is for, who uses it and why? Maybe you can add a wireframe to explain the situation?

Comment: This is for a Loan eligibility, banking product

Comment: What can a verified email account do that a non-verified account cannot?

Comment: There is no way to verify an email without actually sending an email to the user, and having them click a link.

Comment: Editted my question, hope this will help you understand the problem better

Comment: I still don't get the use case (from the user point of view): What does a *work* email have to do with (assumed private) loan eligibility? Does that not introduce a backdoor for (at the worst) discrimination? Your statement that the work email is a "business requirement" to me also says it's about the company and not the user.

Answer (score 1):

UX-wise, asking the user to enter a code typically only works during mandatory verification flows. Any time you give a choice between [Do Work] and [Skip], most users will choose [Skip] (unless [Do Work] provides obvious benefits).

I recommend a link-only approach.  Other than length considerations, there's not much difference between typing/pasting a token vs. stuffing it into a query parameter.

1. When the user first signs up for an account, send them an e-mail "Thank you for signing up. Please verify your e-mail by clicking this link." As long as you don't tell them you are sending this e-mail, the email shouldn't impact conversion (if you do tell them you sent the e-mail, this might trigger a context switch, potentially hurting conversion rates).
2. In the user's account preferences, put the word "(unverified)" next to the user's e-mail address and provide a verify e-mail button which sends a verification e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Since the email verification is not mandatory, conversion rate will be low. To top that the user is expected to input an OTP, which is again extra effort for a non-mandatory field.
Verification through a verify link shared to their email might just make it easier for users to consider verifying the email.

As I understand this being used on a form for Loan eligibility on banking product, I would suggest making the work email verification mandatory - this add more security to the BO requirement and process.

Answer (score 0):

Let the user sign up without verification (Though still send the verification email), but gatekeep them from using your entire product.

Only give them full access to your product after account verification.